# Find new dates for list of deals

Tags: sql, exists

I want to find dates in calendar what not include in table with deals+dates columns by deals. 
Example with expected result in code (T-SQL) . Thx for the advises

```
create table #deals
(id int ,
dates date);

create table #calendar 
(dates date );

create table #result
(id int ,
dates date);

-----calendar table (tbl#1)
insert into #calendar values ('2020-04-19');
insert into #calendar values ('2020-04-20');
insert into #calendar values ('2020-04-21');
-----deals table (tbl#2)
insert into #deals values ('111', '2020-04-19');
insert into #deals values ('111', '2020-04-20');
insert into #deals values ('222', '2020-04-18');
----expected result table 
insert into #result values ('111', '2020-04-21');
insert into #result values ('222', '2020-04-19');
insert into #result values ('222', '2020-04-20');
insert into #result values ('222', '2020-04-21');

select * from #calendar; 
select * from #deals;
select * from #result
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate all combinations of deals and dates and then remove the ones that exist:

```
select d.id, c.date
from (select distinct id from #deals) d cross join
     #calendar c left join
     #deals dd
     on dd.id = d.id and dd.date = c.date
where dd.id is null;
```

Comment: Thx, great. But I think , this method is not the most effective?!

Comment: @SergeyFido . . . If you have an alternative, they can be compared.  I can't think of another obvious way to do what you want -- except for minor variations on this, such as using `exists` or `except` (if your database supports that).